# Can you make retractable sticky pistons, while extended, in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I was wondering if there is a mod or something to allow sticky pistons that are extended to be pulled or pushed by other pistons?

There must be a way to make this work, because trying to make a 4-tier door and timing everything from a single T flip flop is nearly impossible - not to mention it takes up a ton of room.

Comment: If you are just looking for a way to make a 4-tier door I suggest checking out MumboJumbo on Youtube as I know he has made a plethora of doors including a 4x4. If you want to use a mod just to make this work keep in mind that everyone else you want to share your piston creation with will need to install the mod for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** push a non-retracted piston with a sticky piston. However, this will not help your problem. There are no mods out there that will allow this that I can find that are of usable quality.